# pyspark - dynamically type cast and alias using metadata defined in json variable

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using Apache Spark 3.0.1

I have an incoming data frame `df_src` like the following.

```
df_src = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
            ('1', 'foo', '2020-02-03', '2020-03-24T09:21:20+00:00'),
            ('2', 'bar', '2019-01-29', '2020-01-15T17:00:20+00:00'),
        ],
        ['a_col', 'b_col', 'c_col', 'd_col']
    )
```

[image]

I also have metadata (as json object within array) that needs to be applied, - I would like to apply this metadata to `df_src`
I need to do 3 things

1. select only needed columns (projection)
2. apply data type
3. apply alias

I have tried the following and got steps 1 and 2.

```
import json
metadata_json = """
[
 {"source_field":"a_col", "alias":"x_col", "datatype":"string"}
,{"source_field":"b_col", "alias":"y_col", "datatype":"timestamp"}
,{"source_field":"c_col", "alias":"z_col", "datatype":"string"}
]
"""

# Transform json input to python objects
metadata_dict = json.loads(metadata_json)

# Filter python objects with list comprehensions
source_fields = [x['source_field'] for x in metadata_dict]
print(source_fields)


# 1) projection - DONE i.e. my incoming data frame had d_col which I do not need - so doing select here based on metadata_json
df = df_src.select(source_fields)

# 2) apply data type - DONE i.e. from metata_json I am selecting fields that needs to be timestamp and casting.
for column in metadata_dict:
  if column['datatype'] == 'timestamp':
    df_dest = df.withColumn(column['source_field'], col(column['source_field']).cast("timestamp"))
    
# 3) apply alias ?
```

[image]

After step 2 my destination data frame `df_dest` looks as above.

Now, how do I apply alias dynamically based on metadata_json above using pyspark? (Also please suggest if there is an elegant way to do all the 3 steps, I cannot change the metadata_json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your input object (and straightforward strings), consider something like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


# string backticks to protect the names against "." and other characters
input_df.select(
    *[
        F.col(f"`{x["source_field"]}`").cast(x["datatype"]).alias(x["alias"])
        for x in metadata_dict
    ]
)
```

If your strings become a little bit more complex, a simple `cast()` may not hack it. If that's the case, consider wrapping the entire `F.col().cast().alias()` statement implements a simple strategy pattern (or `if ... elif ... else` switch) that can handle more complex logic.